# How to get string value from php function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to execute a function in php that returns a string but I couldn't find a clear explanation.

I would really like if you could answer for this example.

this is my php file, **hello.php**:

```php
<?php
  function HelloWorld()
  {
    return "Hello!";
  }
?>
```

and let's say this is my javascript in my HTML file

MainPage.html

```html
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    sayHello()
    {
      alert(/*This is where I want My php to call*/);   
    }
  </script>  
  <input type = "submit" onclick="sayHello()"/>
</body>
```

What I am asking is how can I get my php and use functions in it succesfully

Comment: `alert('<?php echo HelloWorld()?>');`

Comment: You will need to call the server-side page *(hello.php)* and execute the function, then do whatever you wish with the response.

Comment: I am sorry but this doesn't work. I have a couple of jquery codes. And this breaks other codes somehow..

Comment: @Viral that won't work because the MainPage.html  isn't a server-side document. hence MainPage - **.html**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do one thing, change `MainPage.html` to `MainPage.php`.

So, you `MainPage.php` will look like

```
<?php
  function HelloWorld()
  {
    return "Hello!";
  }
?>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    sayHello()
    {
      alert('<?php echo HelloWorld()?>');
    }
  </script>  
  <input type = "submit" onclick="sayHello()"/>
</body>
```

This will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing file extensions:

Make your file speak by echo at the end of file `hello.php`

```
<?php
  function HelloWorld()
  {
    return "Hello!";
  }
  echo HelloWorld();
?>
```

Change `MainPage.html` to call ajax from `hello.php` like,

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#clickme').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url : 'hello.php',
                type : 'GET',
                dataType:'html',
                success : function(data) {           
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
  <input type="button" id="clickme"/>
</body>
```

Also check that both of your files is in the same directory, i used popular JavaScript framework called jQuery for ajax call.

Comment: can you explain how do I choose which function do I call from php file?

Comment: that you have to decide on your php file, see above, i have called `HelloWorld()` by placing `echo` at start, you can call any other function, there are many methodologies, please go through some pages [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp), you will get more idea.